# Dynamic ListView display based on Itemsource {Binding} to ObservableCollection<"this can change and dictates listview style"?>

Tags: xaml, listview, mvvm, uwp, viewmodel

**Summary of the Question:** What is the correct way to manipulate the same, single `ObservableCollection` in a xaml page's viewmodel (binded to the `ListView` of the page ), at runtime in order to show different sets of data, each variation of data providing its own `ListView`-`Style` via a `StyleSelector`?

**Description:** 
I have a UWP xaml page with a single `ListView`, I want this listview to display all different possible data sets the user might want to see. e.g:  A dataset could be between one to 15 columns of data, all with headers. The `ListView`'s `ItemSource` will use binding to an `ObservableCollection` to populate it. The `ObservableCollection` can be populated manually or with one of many `SQL` sourced `DataTable`'s.

```
    <ListView x:Name="UserPageListView"
              ItemsSource="{Binding MainListData, Mode=TwoWay}"                  
              Grid.Column="1"
              Width="auto"
              Background="Gray"
              ItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource UserPage_StyleSelector}">
    </ListView>
```

I have tried binding the `ItemContainerStyleSelector` to provide a xaml `ListView` `Style` (which is stored in a `ResourceDictionary`), based on the data type of the `ObservableCollection`, or at least that was the idea. 
 
 I don't know whether the `ObservableCollection`'s data type should be generic or a defined class per data set to view. The latter makes sense, since a `StyleSelector` would need it for logic to provide the relevant `Style`.  
 
 I used `StyleSelector` instead of `DataTemplateSelector` since I want the Selector to include `HeaderTemplate` as well as `ItemTemplate`(headers of columns change with the different data sets):

```
public class UserPage_StyleSelector:StyleSelector
{
    public Style WatchlistStyle { get; set; }
    public Style UserDetailStyle { get; set; }

    protected override Style SelectStyleCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is WatchlistData)
            return WatchlistStyle;
        if (item is UserDetailData)
            return UserDetailStyle;

        return base.SelectStyleCore(item, container);
    }
}
```

`Style` example in `ResourceDictionary`:

```
    <Style TargetType="ListView"
       x:Key="UserDetail_ListView"
       x:Name="UserDetail_ListView">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="12" 
                      Background="{ThemeResource SystemBaseLowColor}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="UserDetails"
                               Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                   Text="{Binding Details}"
                   FontSize="12"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

`StyleSelector` defined in the xaml page:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <viewModels:UserPage_StyleSelector x:Key="UserPage_StyleSelector"
                                       WatchlistStyle="{StaticResource WatchList_ListView}"
                                       UserDetailStyle="{StaticResource UserDetail_ListView}"/>

</Page.Resources>
```

The `ResourceDictionary` is defined in app.xaml.cs. Have I complicated this endeavour far too much by using the wrong approach?

Answer (score 0):

`ItemContainerStyle` target type is `ListViewItem`, so you can't make `ListView` style in `ItemContainerStyleSelector`.

Derive from your requirement `(headers of columns change with the different data sets)`, you need make `GroupStyleSelector` and `ItemTemplateSelector` for different header and columns.

```
<GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock
                    Margin="5"
                    FontSize="25"
                    Foreground="Gray"
                    Text="{Binding Name}"
                    />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
</GroupStyle>
```

For more detail please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.CollectionViewSource?view=winrt-19041).